# Significance test for time spent on three regions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design, mice

I am dealing with an experiment 
Three groups of mice. Each mouse spend time in an arena within the arena we placed three objects. 
I want to test, for each group if the time spent on each object is significant more comparing to the other objects. 
Afterwards I'd like to compare the result between the groups and check if a significant difference appeared only in 1 or 2 groups. 
What is the right test to use?

Comment: It looks like an ANOVA problem.

Comment: But do all the criterias for ANOVA apply?

Comment: ANOVA is not an appropriate analysis method because the dependent variable is a vector of times, that if I understand the set-up, should probably be converted into proportions. You probably want to convert each time vector into a proportion vector and use a dirichlet-regression sort of approach. Here is a reference for an R implementation I've never used but seems legit: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DirichletReg/vignettes/DirichletReg-vig.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you don't have that many mice so you'll have to test if the data (time that each mouse spent) is normally distributed.

If not you'll need to use a non-parametric test for comparing the means. I suggest that you test if there is a significant difference and then comment on the direction of the difference (which of the mean is higher/lower)

Comment: Thanks! Do you any specific pair of tests in mind?

Comment: @Meni Friedman's test probabaly